# Связь с Matlab микроконтроллера PIC через UART

Tags: c, embedded, pic, микроконтроллеры

Делаю один проект с UART, где использую микроконтроллер PIC и Matlab. Когда я должен нажать букву "l", то сервопривод должен влево поворачивать, когда "r" то направо. Но не хочет. И не нахожу проблему, почему именно.Заранее спасибо.
Код:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc7c14a403a651a05a03

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста, код в текст вопроса или, если он большой, поместите на сайт, где его сразу видно (https://gist.github.com/ или http://pastebin.com).

Comment: Вам для начала нужно выяснить, что у вас не работает - UART или интерпретация данных. Вы пробовали проверить, идет ли обмен? (Можно эхо сделать, например)

Comment: да, обмен идёт , UART работает

Comment: В таком случае не могли бы вы исправить и присоединить к вопросу код, который должен "поворачивать" сервопривод. Потому что сейчас там меняется какая-то необъявленная переменная x, и совершенно неясно, с чего бы там вообще чему-то работать. Плюс указать формат обмена.

Comment: поправил  в  github

Comment: И почему его положение должно меняться при приходе 'l' или 'r'?

Comment: задумал контролировать его через UART. Там в коде SetingServo меняет угол сервопривода.

Comment: Только эта переменная не меняется внутри `dvijenie`

Comment: SetingServo = y;

Comment: Это присвоение происходит только при входе в функцию main, в дальнейшем значения не синхронизуются

Comment: по вашему  что можна зделать?  сразу в interrupt isr_tmr ?